# Selenium WebDriver, wait while displayed loading div

Tags: c#, selenium

at first: 
 - Selenium 2.0 with Webdriver 
 - for IExplorer, Chrome and Firefox 
 - current Webdriver and Selenium dll's 
 - Windows 8.1 
 - Visual Studio 2013 C#

i would test my site. The pages will be loaded with ajax. If i would change the page, it will be display a loading div (div #wartenDialog). Now i would wait while display this div, before i change to next page.

the problem is, sometimes there is a small delay until show loading div and by a fast computer/internet there is no loading div.

i have try this functions:

```
public static void WaitWhileElementVisible(RemoteWebDriver _driver, By _locator)
{
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeout));
  wait.Until(drv => !Exists(drv, _locator));
}

private static bool Exists(IWebDriver _drv, By _locator)
{
  return (ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(_locator) != null);
}
```

Now it's always run in Timeout.

Comment: You should show also your relevant HTML and how you call `WaitWhileElementVisible` with parameters.  Also I do not understand why you create custom `Exists` method with parameter  `IWebDriver _drv` that is not used at all.

Comment: the _drv is a leftover from an other try. i had use the _drv.FindElement(_locator) methode

Answer (score 0):

Your approach to wait for element to visible is correct. But a little modification to your code will do the trick.

```
public static void WaitWhileElementVisible(RemoteWebDriver _driver, By _locator)
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeout));
    wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(WebDriverTimeoutException));
    wait.Until(drv => !Exists(drv, _locator));
}
```

`IgnoreExceptionTypes()` will ignore the provided exception type. This code is working for me.

Hope this resolve your issue.

Comment: thanks for the fast answer. Unfortunately, this did not change. I have one own mistake: the css syntax must be div#wartenDialog and not div #wartenDialog, but I get the same result. I have detect the ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(_locator) != null methode always returns true. now i use the _drv.FindElement(_locator).GetCssValue("display") != "none" expression and it works

Comment: I have change the expression into the _drv.FindElement(_locator).Displayed; expression and it works too. Maybe a better syntax

Comment: @Gamer2015 Good to hear that you resolved the issue. If you want to ignore any exceptions those occur while using `WebDriverWait` you should use `IgnoreExceptionTypes` (in your case it is `TimeoutException`). I came across one issue using `Displayed` method. If element is not present on the DOM, `FindElement` method throws `NoSuchElement` exception. If element present on the page it works fine. I avoided using `Displayed` method most of the cases.